# Camera doesn't follow player

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The camera goes the opposite way of the character. I want the camera to follow so that the character is in the center of the screen constantly.

I've tried using a transform(x - canvas.width/2, y - canvas.height/2) like shown in the fiddle, but it does opposite of what I want it to.

This is the relevant code:

```
function render(){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x - canvas.width / 2, y - canvas.height / 2); //This is what i've tried
    tileX = 0;
    tileY = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {

        if(map[i][j] == 0){
        if(grassReady){
            ctx.drawImage(grassImage, tileX, tileY);
        }
        }
        if(map[i][j] == 1){
        if(sandReady){
            ctx.drawImage(sandImage, tileX, tileY);
        }
        }
        tileX += 128;
    }
    tileX = 0;
    tileY += 128;
    }

    if(playerReady){
    ctx.drawImage(playerImage, x, y);
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle of what it looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/0szen7mr/1/

Thanks in advance for your time!

**Edit: Solution was to change
`ctx.translate(x - canvas.width / 2, y - canvas.height / 2);`

To

`ctx.translate(-x + canvas.width / 2, -y + canvas.height / 2);`**

Comment: I think you made the mistake of intertwining your initial render with updating the canvas and it's making it very difficult to troubleshoot. You're going to want to separate the render of your player from the map.

Comment: Sorry, I'll update the code to make it easier to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know, (0,0) is in the top left corner of the Javascript canvas, and increases as you go down and to the right. At the start, you set `x` and `y` so that `render` does `ctx.translate(0,0)` because `x=canvas.width/2` and same for `y`. The issue comes when you begin using the arrow keys to move. So when you press left, for example,  you're decreasing the `x` value. This matters because you can think of `translate` as moving where the origin of the canvas (0,0) is. And that does match what actually happens. When you press left, the `x` coordinate decreases, and the origin (top left corner of the map) moves to the left. A similar thing happens in the `y` direction.

This is basically what happens when you transform a function. Think of `y=x^2`, and how `y=(x-5)^2` is shifted to the *right* even though you're subtracting from the `x` value.

To fix it, you can make your update function this:

```
function update(){
    if (38 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
        y += speed;
    }
    if (40 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
        y -= speed;
    }
    if (37 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
        x += speed;
    }
    if (39 in keysDown) { // Player holding right
        x -= speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay but then how would I change the code to match what I need?

Comment: In your `update` function you can just switch the signs. Change `+=` to `-=` and vice-versa.

Comment: Thats what I thought at first too, but it doesnt fix the problem unfortunately :/

Comment: If I make that change in the jsfiddle, it works fine properly for me.

Comment: Hmm that is odd, don't know what I am doing wrong. Could you paste your update function here?

Comment: Edited my original comment with it

Comment: The camera moves in the right direction, but the character now moves away from the camera :S

Comment: Ah apologies! The sprite isn't loading for me, so I didn't notice it. Revert `update` back to the original and replace your `ctx.translate` with `ctx.translate(-x + canvas.width / 2, -y + canvas.height / 2);`

Comment: Haha, Thank you! I've almost pulled my hair off from this one, turned out to be a pretty simple solution as always. :D